# continuous approximation of a Bernoulli random variable with the same mean

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a Bernoulli random variable with $P(X=1)= \frac{1}{n} $ and $P(X=0)=1- \frac{1}{n} $  for some given $n\geq 2$, $n\in Z_+$. Then $E(X)=\frac{1}{n}$.

Define $Z$ be a continuous random variable with c.d.f. $F(z)=z^{\frac{1}{n-1}}$, $z\in [0,1]$. Then $E(Z)=\frac{1}{n}$.

I thought that  $Z$ is a continuous approximation of $X$ in some sense. For example if $n=2$, then $X$  is discrete  uniform and $Z$ is continuous uniform.

Is there any existing theory or concept  to formalize this idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the sequences $(X_n)_{n \geq 2},(Z_n)_{n \geq 2}$ with respective cumulative distributions for $y \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\begin{aligned}F_{X_n}(y)&=(1-1/n)\mathbf{1}_{[0,1)}(y)+\mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(y)\\
F_{Z_n}(y)&=y^{1/(n-1)}\mathbf{1}_{[0,1)}(y)+\mathbf{1}_{[1,\infty)}(y)
\end{aligned}$$
Then you have $F_{X_n}(y)\to \mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)$ and $F_{Z_n}(y)\to \mathbf{1}_{(0,\infty)}(y)$ pointwise. Since both sequences of cumulative distributions converge to $F_Y(y)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,\infty)}(y)$ at all points of continuity of $F_Y$, we have that $X_n\stackrel{\textrm{d}}{\to} Y,Z_n\stackrel{\textrm{d}}{\to}Y$ where $Y$ is a degenerate random variable i.e. $P(Y=0)=1$. By definition of convergence in distribution and triangle inequality, you have that for any $f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (continuous and bounded) $|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(Z_n)]|\to 0$. The rate of convergence depends on $f$; for example if $f$ is Lipschitz with constant $K$ and $(X_n)_{n \geq 2},(Z_n)_{n \geq 2}$ are on the same probability space we have by Jensen's inequality and again triangle inequality $|E[f(X_n)]-E[f(Z_n)]|\leq KE[|X_n-Z_n|]\leq \frac{2K}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is very helpful.